# A high-powered explanation for $\exp U(n)=2\iff n\mid24$?

Tags: number-theory

In [*What's so special about the divisors of $24$? (Math. Mag., 2012)*](https://doi.org/10.4169/math.mag.85.5.366) it is noted that the [exponent](https://planetmath.org/Exponent) of the group of units modulo $n$, that is the highest order of an element of $U(n):=(\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z)^\times$, is precisely $2$ if and only if the integer $n$ divides $24$. An elementary argument is given (see also [answers here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/524789/242) for a one-line proof), as well as some analytic machinery, but I recall (perhaps not quite accurately) that the number $24$ [shows up a lot in high-powered math](https://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/numbers/24.pdf) related to number theory, like lattices, moonshine, modular forms, string theory etc: suspicious.

If I were a believer in the magical and skeptical of coincidences, I might want to know if there is a high-powered explanation of this fact from the cited theoretical areas (not including asymptotic or statistical heuristics from analytic number theory). Or is it merely a [collision of small numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_Law_of_Small_Numbers)?

Comment: I think the explanation might go in the other direction: Gannon in _Moonshine beyond the Monster_ speculates that this property of $24$ is responsible for its appearance in high-powered math.

Comment: Wikipedia echoes this, stating ["This fact plays a role in monstrous moonshine."](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/24_(number))

Comment: $\exp U(n) = \lambda(n)$, where $\lambda$ is the [Carmichael function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function). From that follows an easy explanation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe I've tracked down what Qiaochu was referencing in Gannon's *Moonshine beyond the Monster*, pg168-169 §2.5 (alas, five pages too late). I can't claim to understand any of it.

$\qquad$ [image: 24]