# Minimum size group with an element that is its own inverse

Tags: group-theory

I Believe I saw a proof to the effect that groups of a minimum order were guaranteed to have at least one non-identity element that is its own inverse. I believe that the order was 24, but I cannot find said paper any more. Is this in fact true and can you provide a proof of this fact or refer me to a proof of this fact?

Comment: Do you mean a non-identity element that is its own inverse? Then you are asking when is a group guaranteed to have idempotent. Many groups do not have these, even of very high order.

Comment: In fact, any odd order group cannot have such an element.

Comment: An idempotent is not its own inverse. But an element of order 2 will be a nonidentity element which is its own inverse. I think any group of even order has one of these: $p|o(G)$ implies $G$ has an element of order $p$.

Comment: what are you trying to use this for?  Maybe if we know the reason we can help you reformulate this question in a more helpful way?

Comment: The overachring purpose is a proof that every group that has only trivial subgroups is finite and prime. Showing that for finite groups is trivial. I was trying to show that there is at least one subgroup in every infinite group. Our class has not dealt with infinite groups in much length so I was trying to se if their would be at least on non identity element that is its own inverse. But I see that infinite groups have an infinite number of subgroups. This however is not imeadiatly apparent to me. But it is sufficient to complete the proof.

Comment: [Klein four-group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klein_four-group) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are perhaps thinking of the note [*What is special about the divisors of $24$?*](http://math.illinoisstate.edu/schebol/divisorsof24.pdf) where it is shown that if $n$ is a natural number such that every invertible element in ${\bf Z}/n{\bf Z}$ is its own inverse (or, equivalently, the group of units $U(n):=({\bf Z}/n{\bf Z})^\times$ has [exponent](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Exponent_of_a_group) $2$), then $n\mid24$. The converse holds true as well: if $n\mid24$, then $U(n)$ has exponent $2$. This simple, elementary fact may underlie a lot of deeper stuff ["related to number theory, like lattices, moonshine, modular forms, string theory etc."](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/217006/a-high-powered-explanation-for-exp-un-2-iff-n-mid24)

Comment: That was the paper I was considering, but alas I have mixed my number theory with my abstract algebra. All the same thank you very much.

Comment: Another fun fact is that finite subgroups of ${\rm GL}_2({\bf Q})$ have order dividing $24$. This is a special case of theory worked out by Minkowski. See [Part II of Lorenz's talk](https://math.temple.edu/~lorenz/talks/MatrixGroups.pdf).

Answer (score 3):

Every group has an element that is its own inverse, namely the identity. If you mean a non-identity self-inverse element, then this is the same thing as an element of order $2$. A finite group $G$ has an element of order $2$ if and only if $|G|$ is even. Thus there is no result of the sort you want.

Comment: Thank you this helped direct me the correct way.