# Determine all positive integers $n \ge 2$ that satisfy the condition for $a,b$ rel prime to $n$ we have $a \equiv b \pmod n$ iff $ab \equiv 1 \pmod n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Determine all positive integers $n \ge 2$ that satisfy the following condition: for $a,b$ relatively prime to $n$ we have $a \equiv b \pmod n$ if and only if $ab \equiv 1 \pmod n$.

The condition is equivalent to the condition that $a \equiv b \pmod n \iff a^2 \equiv 1 \pmod n$. Thus we're looking for $n$'s that satisfy $a^2 \equiv 1 \pmod n$.

Now by the Chinese remainder theorem we can split this congruence using the prime factorization of $n$ and I think we will get that if $n=p_1^{\alpha_1} \cdots p_k^{\alpha_k}$, then  $$\begin{align} a^2 &\equiv 1 \pmod{p_1^{\alpha_1}} \\ &\vdots \\a^2 & \equiv 1 \pmod{p_k^{\alpha_k}}\end{align}$$

the question is now how I can use this information to get some equivalent statement from which I can derive the information for $n$?

Comment: You want $\lambda(n)\le 2$. See [Carmichael function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function).

Comment: The key is that $a^2\equiv 1\pmod n$ FOR ALL $a$ with $(a,n)=1$.

Comment: **Beware** that there is a gap in [one of the answers](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2091283/242) in the linked dupes.