# What's so special about the number 24 in the definition of the Ramanujan tau function?

Tags: number-theory, modular-forms, arithmetic-functions

I'm learning about the Ramanujan tau function $\tau \colon \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{Z}$ defined by $$\tau(1)q + \tau(2)q^2 + \tau(3)q^3 + \ldots = q \prod_{n = 1}^{\infty} \left(1 - q^n\right)^{24}.$$
However, I'm confused why the number $24$ is so special here. What if we used a different number instead of $24?$ All of the properties of the Ramanujan tau function I could find either had nothing to do with $24$ (such as the property that $\tau$ is multiplicative) or had some specific numbers in them.

Comment: The RHS is a  modular form and an eigenfunction of the Hecke operators. $24$ is the magical number that makes it work. For example with $48$ it is still a modular form but not an eigenform anymore.

Comment: The fact that 24 is special is a mystery of Mathematics. It is distantly related to the fact that the group $S_6$ has a non-trivial outer automorphism and that the Leech Lattice exists. No-one has yer=t written a book on $24$ as a social mathematical number ...

Comment: Also, the function can't be multiplicative if the number used wasn't $24.$

Comment: Cf. [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/217006/a-high-powered-explanation-for-exp-un-2-iff-n-mid24/217157#217157)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$24$ is the value such that $\Delta$ is a weight $k$ modular form with only one simple zero on the modular curve (at $\infty$).

Then, let $f$ be another weight $k$ cusp form. So $\frac{f}{\Delta}$ is a weight $0$ modular form, by the maximum modulus principle it has to be constant.

For each Hecke operator $T_n \Delta$ is a weight $k$ cusp form, thus equal to $a_n \Delta$ for some $a_n$, which has to be the $n$-th coefficient of $\Delta$.

Whence the coefficients of $\Delta$ are multiplicative.